# What is the linkage of a block scope identifier with static storage duration?

Tags: c

I believe the answer is no linkage because the standard only guarantees that a file scope identifier with static storage duration have internal linkage. However, it seems that recursive calls to a function which has an identifier with static storage duration does not impose additional memory for local variables. In other words, at any stage of the recursive process, **the identifier always denotes the same object**, which is weird given that it has no linkage. Why is that?

```
void recursive(void) {
    static int a;
    printf("%d", &a);   // it repeatedly spits out the same address.
    recursive();
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it spit out the same address?  The whole point of declaring `a` `static` is to make it persistent across invocations.

Comment: Also it is not having base case.So at one point it will exhaust all stack space...

Comment: It's certainly the same linkage as the containing function. Only automatic variables have no linkage.

Comment: @jamesdlin I agree this ought to be that way considering the stack. However, it somewhat looks to me a linkage because every new **a** denotes the same object(=what a linkage is for)!

Comment: @Il-seobBae: Is this a question about how things are or how the standard describes them? (For the latter, I'm currently stuck, the former is easy.)

Comment: @mafso I don't see any reason to believe every **a** denotes the same object in every recursive stage. The standard only guarantees literally its lifetime. It's possible that **a**s are instantiated at every stage and they last to the end of the program execution.

Comment: Linkage has nothing to do with the behavior you are observing. Linkage is about the rules for resolving an object name to the object address. Typically it comes to play when there are multiple translation units involved (i.e. several obj files), shared libraries, etc.

Comment: @Il-seobBae What do you mean "every new `a`"?  There is only *one* instance of `a` (and it is *not* on the stack), it's initialized once (in C) when the program starts up (along with global variables), not each time the function is invoked.

Comment: @Il-seobBae: I think I see your confusion (if there still is any); the `a` in your code is always the same and denotes the same object. In a way, your question could be "why isn't it the same for identifiers denoting an object with automatic storage duration?", the answer to which can be found in C11 (n1570) 6.2.4 p6 _[...] If the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the object [with automatic storage duration] is created each time. [...]_ Such a requirement is missing for objects with static storage duration, thus the identifier always denotes the same object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local static variables have no linkage (or more precisely their linkage is *none*). From N1570 (C11 draft) 6.2.2 *Linkages of identifiers* (emphasis mine):

> 6) The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to
>   be anything other than an object or a function; an identifier declared
>   to be a function parameter; a **block scope identifier** for an object
>   declared without the storage-class specifier `extern`.

However `static` specifier imposes that such variable has *static storage duration*, which is kind of different thing. What you are refering to is lifetime of object. Such variables denotes objects, that have lifetime of whole execution of program and are intialized once, conceptually before program's actual startup.

6.2.4 *Storage durations of objects*:

> 2) The *lifetime* of an object is the portion of program execution during
>   which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists,
>   **has a constant address**,<sup>33)</sup> and **retains its last-stored value**
>   throughout its lifetime.<sup>34)</sup> If an object is referred to outside of its
>   lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes
>   indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the
>   end of its lifetime.
>
> 3) An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class
>   specifier `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class specifier `static`, has *static storage duration*. Its
>   lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value
>   is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

Comment: I've already read all that you just referred to. I'm just confused. Suppose every recursive stage entails an additional memory space and that object lives to the end of the program. In that situation, is it illegal according to the standard? I think it is legal because the standard only guarantees its lifetime not the equality between objects. I mean how come those identifiers denote the same object...?

Comment: @Il-seob Bae: See updated answer, especially 6.2.4/2.

Comment: 6.2.4/6 clearly states that, whenever the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created each time. I don't see why 6.2.4/2 cancels away 6.2.4/6. That's about the lifetime of an **object** and an object can be instantiated many times. I think they are two different things.

Comment: @Il-seob Bae: Subclause 6.2.4/6 refers to objects with _automatic storage duration_ (if you read closely), that are separate thing.

Comment: Although it's not directly related to the question, What is the lifetime of an object with automatic storage duration? It seems the standard does not guarantee anything about its lifetime. Are we just supposed to be happy with the fact that it is usually implemented by a stack?

Comment: @l-seob Bae: Its lifetime ends with scope. For example in case of block scope it's `}` character that represents end of current block scope. Every time when `}` is encountered such object have to be destroyed. In practice it means that its value is simply gone and cannot be reached anymore. I believe it's described somewhere. In general Standard is rather not easy to anticipate.

Comment: @Il-seobBae, it's discussed in C11 (n1570) 6.2.4 p6/p7 (cf. my comment above). For writing code, the simplification "the lifetime corresponds to the scope of the identifier" is safe. In case your curious, the details: For a non-VLA, it's from the beginning of the enclosing block (note, that this is possibly before the corresponding identifier is in scope) to the end of the scope. For VLAs, it's simply the scope of the identifier (a jump within a block out of the scope of a VLA destroys it, as opposed to non-VLAs, which keep their last-stored value in this case).